# Scala - flatten Seq containing Seq

Tags: scala

Given:

```
Seq(1,2,3) map {
  case 1 => 11
  case 2 => Seq(12,13,14)
  case 3 => 15
}
```

How can I elegantly flatten this to a `Seq[Int]` containing `Seq(11,12,13,14,15)` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
Seq(1,2,3) flatMap {
  case 1 => Seq(11)
  case 2 => Seq(12,13,14)
  case 3 => Seq(15)
}
```

res0: Seq[Int] = List(11, 12, 13, 14, 15)

Comment: Did you really solve OP's issue? It seems to me, that list is already created and you should flatten it, isn't it?

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg I assume that the OP will need to make adaptations to solve the real problem but we can't know for sure what those are. This shows that you can map inputs to `Seq`s and use a `flatMap` to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it:

```
implicit def unitSeq[T](x: T): Seq[T] = Seq(x)

Seq(1, 2, 3) flatMap {
  case 1 => 11
  case 2 => Seq(12, 13, 14)
  case 3 => 15
}
```

res0: Seq[Int] = List(11, 12, 13, 14, 15)

Answer (score 1):

When you have `Seq(1,2,3)` you have a `Seq[Int]`.

after your map operation you have a problem though

```
val mapped = Seq(1,2,3) map {
  case 1 => 11
  case 2 => Seq(12,13,14)
  case 3 => 15
}
```

What is the type of `mapped`? A reasonable answer to this could be that it doesn't have a type. That's close to the truth. The resulting type is `Seq[Any]`. Unfortunately, this is a completely useless type. It's not something you could do anything useful with in a typesafe way, and a good point could be made that Scala shouldn't have allowed this type to be inferred in the first place.

The solution is not to let it get that far in the first place, but map to something that does have a sensible type. The solution shown by Simon is a reasonable approach:

```
val mapped = Seq(1,2,3) map {
  case 1 => Seq(11)
  case 2 => Seq(12,13,14)
  case 3 => Seq(15)
  case _ => throw new Exception("uh oh, didn't account for this to happen!")
}
```

Now mapped is a `Seq[Seq[Int]]`, and we can do more useful things with it, for example flatten it to a `Seq[Int]` with `mapped.flatten`

But we can get there in one go. There is an operation called `flatMap` on `Seq[A]` that takes a function `A => Seq[A]` as it's argument, and returns a single `Seq[A]`.

```
val flatmapped = Seq(1,2,3) flatMap {
  case 1 => Seq(11)
  case 2 => Seq(12,13,14)
  case 3 => Seq(15)
  case _ => throw new Exception("uh oh, didn't account for this to happen!")
}
```

`flatmapped` is now `Seq(11, 12, 13, 14, 15)`

---

*Aside*

It turns out, by the way, that it's very useful to have this operation on all sorts of parameterized types: `(F[A], A => F[A]) => F[A]`

For example:

```
Option[A].flatMap(a: A => Option[A]): Option[A]

def squareroot(x: Double): Option[Double] = if (x >= 0) Some(Math.sqrt(x))
                                            else None

Some(4.0).flatMap(squareroot) == Some(2.0)
Some(-1.0).flatMap(squareroot) == None
None.flatMap(squareroot) == None
```

or

```
Future[A].flatMap(a: A => Future[A]): Future[A]
```

This operation is sometimes called `flatMap`, and sometimes called `bind`, and sometimes represented as `=>>`, and if a type (call it `F[A]`) that support this operation, and support another operation that can create an `F[A]` from an `A` as well (sometimes called `point` and sometimes called `return`), and follow some conditions on how these operations compose, `F[A]` forms a `Monad`

Comment: `Scala shouldn't have allowed this type to be inferred in the first place.` You do get a warning about it, though

Comment: By default? I didn't know that, but that's progress :)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have this list, you may do `flatMap` to achieve the required result:

```
val list = Seq(11, Seq(12, 13, 14), 15)

val flattened = list.flatMap {
    case x: Int => Seq(x)
    case y: Seq[Int] => y
}
```

To avoid warnings (although, it'll not help you in making this code type-safe) you may use following:

```
val flattened = list.flatMap {
    case x: Int => Seq(x)
    case y: Seq[_] => y.asInstanceOf[Seq[Int]]
}
```

Comment: Did you try this? You get a warning about type erasure and end up with a Seq[Any],  not Seq[Int].  `case y:Seq[_] => y` would make it a bit clearer that information about what's in the sequence is lost (and avoids the warning).

Comment: @Paul Mmm, I'm getting this warning, still, the type of `flattened` is `Seq[Int]`.

Comment: I don't see how it can be. Try `val list = Seq(11, Seq("s", "y", "x"), 15)`  but don't change your definition of `flattened`. It works without error, but definitely doesn't return a `Seq[Int]`!

Comment: @Paul The funny thing is it's returning `Seq[Int]`,  cause it thinks `Seq("s", "y", "x")` to be `Seq[Int]` (after type erasure it is): https://gist.github.com/ginz/476f62dfc6cc7bd66d03. So I think this code is working, but is kinda dangerous. I'll try to find the better solution maybe :)

Comment: It's not returning `Seq[Int]` for me. It returns `Seq[Any]`. Are you sure that the compiler is deducing a `Seq[Int]` type for `flattened`, or just assuming it?

Comment: @Paul I'm quite sure, you may see output of REPL in previous message. Scala version: 2.11.2

Comment: I think the compiler's probably doing sometthing odd here, as it's certainly not a Seq[Int] (as you can see from `flattened.map{x=>x*2}` which gives a run-time exception. I don't know why the worksheet I was using gets it right.

Comment: Just `case y: Seq[_] => y` removes the warning for me

Comment: @Paul it removes warning, but it won't give you `Seq[Int]`, which is surely what OP wants. What compiler does is not that odd, it sees `Seq` and I specified, that `Seq` is `Seq[Int]` (which are indistinguishable in runtime), so all the returned values are `Seq[Int]`, then the resulting value is `Seq[Int]`. What you have seen is the result of me "lying" to compiler about parameter type of `Seq`.

Comment: Ah, OK. I see. I feel that is wrong though - it's better to return Seq[Any] given the `flattened  : Seq[Int] = List(11, s, y, x, 15)` demonstrates it really isn't a Seq[Int]. Anyway, that's equine necrophiliac flagellation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78431/discussion-between-dmitry-ginzburg-and-paul).

Comment: Sorry, not got the time.

Comment: @Paul it was an accident :)